# Link table with 3 tables - Schema design

Tags: c#, sql, schema

I'm looking at a way of implementing an 'Upload Attachment' feature to a system. There are 2 areas that these attachments could apply to, Survey Answers and Staff Actions. I would like a link table because I'd like a way of implementing an Attachments repository, so they can apply to Answers and Actions and not have to upload the same document again. Could I simply create a link table such as:

INT - AttachmentId

INT - AppliesTo -> Enum in the system (1 if Answer and 2 if Action)

INT- AppliesToId -> The Id of either the    Action or Answer

Is this a bad design? I have a feeling I'm going about this the wrong way.

This is my first post so appologies if its not up to scratch!

Many thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

This would not be inappropriate from a design standpoint, but with GUID's being used as your primary keys, you can probably drop the AppliesTo field, as GUIDs are guaranteed to be unique.

Below is an example that would look up all attachments for a specified survey answer:

```
SELECT
    AttachmentId
FROM
    Attachments
WHERE
    AppliesToId = @SurveyAnswerId
```

Comment: Woops, knew I'd make a mistake I'm actualy using ints for my ID's. I've updated the question, apologies about that.

Comment: You may want to consider switching to GUIDs for this application, as you could derive some benefit from the uniqueness.  See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad design, but you might find this design more useful:

```
Attachment
AttachmentId (pkey)

Answer
AnswerId (pkey)
AttachmentId (fkey)

Action
ActionId (pkey)
AttachmentId (fkey)
```

This allows you to have Attachments with no actions, without setting a data value to `NULL` and a siple join shows all actions and answers for the same attachment, rather than a conditional join

(Pseudocode)

```
select * from Attachment
outer join Answer on Answer.AttachmentId = Attachment.AttachmentId
outer join Action on Action.AttachmentId = Attachment.AttachmentId
```

If actions / answers can have multiple attachments associated with them, then you would modify this to include a cross-join:

```
Attachment
AttachmentId (pkey)

Answer
AnswerId (pkey)

Action
ActionId (pkey)

AttachmentAnswer
AttachmentAnswerId (pkey)
AttachmentId (fkey)
AnswerId (fkey)

AttachmentAction
AttachmentActionId (pkey)
AttachmentId (fkey)
ActionId (fkey)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I dont understand the need for the bottom solution. Wouldnt the AnserId and AttachmentId be enough to allow for multiple attachment?

Comment: The AttachmentAction cross-table is only needed if you need to maintain a many-to-many relationship with Actions as well as Answers. You might not...